# Center Grid Based on Device Width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Grid (on my screen, 2 rows: 4 boxes and 1 box) that I want to center on the screen based on the width of the screen. No matter if there's 4 boxes or 2 boxes in the first row it should be centered in the screen.

I know I can achieve this with javascript but my question is - is this achievable in CSS?

I have some very simple code and a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUaHz/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>       
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#container{
    width: 93%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

ul li{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla CSS solution, http://jsfiddle.net/MUaHz/3/ :

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#container{
    width: 93%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #009900;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px;

    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000099;
    text-align: center;
}

ul li{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use This

```
#container{
position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 93%; height: 200px;
}
ul li{
position: relative; top: -50%; left: -50%; width: 100%; 
height: 100%; background-color:red; color: white;
margin-bottom: 5px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

> http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/MUaHz/2/

See This Link : [Link](https://coderwall.com/p/quutdq?i=9&p=1&q=author%3aelad2412&t%5B%5D=elad2412)